# Pass API data when tap on CollectionVC to TableVC

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass data from a news Api to a tableView, but I'm having an issue, the data is returning nil when it get's pass to the SectorNewsVC, And by the time it gets to the infoVC it's still nil, however when I print the data before it gets pass it there. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and, how I can go about fixing it? Thank You!!

This is where I'm creating the URLSession and fetching the data, and attempting to pass the data over to the Viewcontroller which is calling the  fetchSectorNews() to retrive the data from an API.

```swift
struct FetchCategoryResponse {
    
    let sectorUrl = "https://stocknewsapi.com/api/v1/category?section=alltickers&items=50&type=article&token=\(Key.api_key)"
    
    func fetchSectorNews(sector: String) {
        let urlString = "\(sectorUrl)&sector=\(sector)"
        performRequest(urlString: urlString)
        print(urlString)
    }
    
    func performRequest(urlString: String) {
        // create url
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            // create url session
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            // give session a task
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    if let news = self.parseJson(sectorData: safeData) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let vc = SectorNewsVC()
                            vc.dataToPass = news
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    // parse the jason data
    func parseJson(sectorData: Data) -> SectorModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(CatergoryData.self, from: sectorData)
            
            let newsUrl = decodedData.data[1].title
            let imageUrl = decodedData.data[1].news_url
            let title = decodedData.data[1].title
            let source = decodedData.data[1].source_name
            
            
            let sectorPayload = SectorModel(url: newsUrl, image: imageUrl, title: title, source: source)
            
            // this sectorpayload gets saved to the news var in the performrequest() bc its being return
            return sectorPayload
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
} // END Struct
```

so in this ViewController I'm setting up the collectionViewController and calling the fetchSectorNews() and passing in the title of the label as the argunemt for the function, while trying to pass the data over to the detialViewController

```swift
var titleArr = ["Technology", "Materials", "HealthCare"]
    var dataToPass: SectorModel?
    var fetchNews = FetchCategoryResponse()

extension SectorNewsVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titleArr.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! SectorCollectionCell
        
        cell.listLabel.text = titleArr[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let curentIndex = indexPath.item
        
        if curentIndex == 0 {
            fetchNews.fetchSectorNews(sector: "technology")
        }
        else if curentIndex == 1 {
            fetchNews.fetchSectorNews(sector: "materials")
        }
        else if curentIndex == 2 {
            fetchNews.fetchSectorNews(sector: "healthcare")
        }
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
    } // end cv()
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue" {
            if let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
                let detailVC = segue.destination as! infoVC
                detailVC.newData = dataToPass
                print(indexPath)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
Here is where I want to display the data
class infoVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var newData: SectorModel?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        tableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1926331222, green: 0.2233074605, blue: 0.3540094197, alpha: 1)
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DifferentSectorCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("tap")
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! DifferentSectorCell
        
        
        cell.titleLabel.text = "hey"
        cell.sourceLabel.text = "hello"
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach.  Sending the section to the child controller, and do the request on the child. Here is what has worked for me before

on the parent controller:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let curentIndex = indexPath.item
    var sector = ""
    if curentIndex == 0 {
        sector = "technology"
    }
    else if curentIndex == 1 {
        sector =  "materials"
    }
    else if curentIndex == 2 {
        sector = "healthcare"
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: sector)
} 


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
            let detailVC = segue.destination as! infoVC
            detailVC.sector = sender as! String
        }
    }
}
```

on the child controller:

```
var sector = ""

override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    fetchNews.fetchSectorNews(sector: self.sector)
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. So how would I be able to take the data and update the TableView?

Comment: After you get the JSON from the performRequest, you assign it to a local variable used in rowAtIndexPath and tableView.reload()

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. I got it.